# Paths with special characters

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I have an `.mo` file with a `CombiTimeTable` that needs to access a `.txt` file located on a path with special characters (Danish '*æøå*'). Both `.mo` file and `.txt` file can be found here:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OMnA8AywtQ1h0MfN_Hp2oMj6cM3LyPHp/view?usp=sharing
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fucvN50DJQyQnGkXjV_LXWPx1N1K-2vgQlaPtgaHg_s

According to Notepad++, both files are encoded as UTF-8 and the Dymola text view indicates that the special character 'æ' in the path looks ok:

[image]

However, when I try to simulate the model I get a path error, indicating that Dymola interprets the 'æ' differently.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the problem? Omitting special characters in the path is not always an option since the files sometimes need to be in shared folders created by colleagues.

Comment: txtfile.txt is not available on your Google drive.

Comment: Tbeu. The link is fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The table implementation is part of MSL and the C implementation doesn't support UTF-8 paths:
https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/blob/master/Modelica/Resources/C-Sources/ModelicaIO.c#L653

You might be able to use mklink to make a link to that directory that does not contain special chars.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for your quick reply. Do you know if there are any future plans to support special character file names in MSL? Otherwise, I think I'll look for other Modelica libraries that can get my external data into the model. BR. Rene

Comment: You could open a ticket on MSL on github with this issue. Depending of available resources this might be fixed quickly.

Comment: The good news is Dymola has a Linux version. The C interface in Linux has no problems with UTF-8 that I'm aware of. Otherwise I would simply use mklink as Adrian suggested: creates a path without Unicode characters so C applications not using Windows-specific file functions can work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of the Modelica Language Specification, but currently not been dealt with: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/136#issuecomment-435584685